# what can travel faster than light through atmosphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light

is there any substance, wave that could actually travel much faster than light in our atmosphere , or is it actually impossible because not even light could pass a wormhole

Comment: See [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation#Astrophysics_experiments) (BTW, I have no idea what you mean by the wormhole)

Comment: A wormhole in the atmosphere?

Comment: Actually you can make light travel very slowly or even stop in some materials. This is known as [Slow Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light). It will then travel more slowly than sound in that material.

Comment: Cerenkov radiation answers your question for water as the medium. I dont know of anything similar for air as a medium. I dont see where the wormhole comes in here.

Comment: Light in the atmosphere travels slower than c, speed of light in a vacuum.  So, some objects that interact less than photons with the atmosphere, can (if they are relativistic, traveling near c) go faster than in-atmosphere light.   It gets complicated, though, because VISIBLE light has much different speed in atmosphere than (for instance) X-rays.